# did google app engine instance share heap and stack?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, heap-memory

If i have a singleton object and a spring singleton scope bean.

what happen if app engine active multiple instance?

will it be still "singleton"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GAE instances run on separate machines in separate JVMs. GAE is a distributed architecture and you should architect your app according to it.

If you have mutithreading enabled, then requests on the same instance will see the same singleton, but not requests on different instances.

To have a common data structures, you should use memcache or datastore.

Comment: another question, is all the request evenly distributed to the instance activated??